# Showing pending build everytime when manually buid in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

The scenarios is like:

Initially we scheduled 3 jobs in jenkins named like core, api-simulator and ui-sumilator. core is main build and triggered build once in week. api-simulator and ui-simulator are dependent. Once core is executed, it triggered other both jobs. So we can say core is parent of other two.

Somehow, someone changed the build triggered rule for core job and set it to 3 times in everyhour. So it executed so many task for core job. Meanwhile it triggered job for other two also.

To stop all those executions, I disabled all 3 jobs.

But now we are facing issue like when we manually click on build now, it starts building but eveytime it generated next task also. If we keep it running, it will generate new schedule one by one continuously.

Even I created new job for same repository and tried but facing same issue.

[screenshot of execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpWLq.png)

Can anyone have an idea how to stop that auto triggered schedule task or remove all those task?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be, that you've configured triggering your downstream jobs from main job and at the same time in your child jobs you've configured main job as upstream job.

So, re-check your configuration, and if that - you need to disable upstream job in child jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @biruk1230 for your answer.

It has been resolved by just done the minor configuration change in Jenkins. I updated Branches to build value to "master". It was "*/master" previously.

You can view from [Reference link](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-30296)